# SceneKit – Stretched texture on a Custom Geometry

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I want to tile the ground with ARKit using custom polygon that creates using selected positions on horizontal plan by user, but tiles are stretched and wont show properly, Maybe problem is from texture coordinates, What's wrong with this code?

```
let vertices: [SCNVector3] = ... //Selected positions by user        
var indices: [Int32] = [Int32(vertices.count)]
var index: Int32 = 0

for _ in vertices {
    indices.append(index)
    index += 1
}
    
let textureCoordinates = [  CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                            CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0),
                            CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1),
                            CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
                         ]
    
let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices)
let uvSource = SCNGeometrySource(textureCoordinates: textureCoordinates)
let indexData = Data(bytes: indices, 
                     count: indices.count * MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData, 
                        primitiveType: .polygon, 
                       primitiveCount: 1, 
                        bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
let geometry = SCNPlane(sources: [vertexSource, uvSource], 
                       elements: [element]) //Creating geometry
   
//Tile material creation
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.isDoubleSided = true
material.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
material.diffuse.wrapT = .repeat

//Tile image to tile polygon
material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "tile")!
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(32, 32, 0)

geometry.firstMaterial = material

//Tiled Plan to put on the ground
let plane = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
//Add custom polygon to sceneView
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(plane)
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to Andy I changed the `contentsTransform` with small change on transform scale, but still have the same issue:

```swift
.init(
 m11: 5, m12: 0,    m13: 0,   m14: 0,
 m21: 0,    m22: 5, m23: 0,   m24: 0,
 m31: 0,    m32: 0,    m33: 1,   m34: 0,
 m41: 0.5,  m42: 0,    m43: 0,   m44: 1)
```

What I expect:

[image: What I expect]

What happens:

[image: What happens]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Texture stretching*** happens due to a wrong texture mapping on the UV map. You have to use `m41` (translate X) and `m42` (translate Y) elements, containing in the fourth column, of [SCNMatrix4](https://medium.com/macoclock/augmented-reality-911-transform-matrix-4x4-af91a9718246). Неre's how a stretch looks like when matrix element `m41` equals to zero:

```
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = .init(
                                       m11: 0.04, m12: 0,    m13: 0,   m14: 0,
                                       m21: 0,    m22: 0.04, m23: 0,   m24: 0,
                                       m31: 0,    m32: 0,    m33: 1,   m34: 0,
                                       m41: 0,    m42: 0,    m43: 0,   m44: 1)
```

[image]

## Offsetting a texture

Everything's changed when you shift a texture along X axis:

```
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = .init(
                                       m11: 0.04, m12: 0,    m13: 0,   m14: 0,
                                       m21: 0,    m22: 0.04, m23: 0,   m24: 0,
                                       m31: 0,    m32: 0,    m33: 1,   m34: 0,
                                       m41: 0.5,  m42: 0,    m43: 0,   m44: 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy! please recheck the question.

Comment: Hi @Hossein, I suppose it's not a good idea to correct a question with new inputs coming from answer. The better approach – publishing a new question...

Comment: I can't understand, nothing has been changed and question is same. I used your contentsTransform and nothing changed.

Comment: Just move a texture along Y axis using `m42` element. I've written about it I the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Also use a scale `m11` and `m22` equal to 2.5.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I think it doesn't work for all polygons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232296/discussion-between-hossein-and-andy-fedoroff).

Comment: Sorry @Hossein, today I have no time for chat(((